# Why "include" folder contains .h files in python disribution (python 3.6.4)

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, header-files

In python distribution .h files are included in the include folder (C:\Users\x_user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\include). I can not find the use of these .h files. How and where are these .h files are used (if in any python file)? I am running python 3.6.4 on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 8):

They are provided so that C extensions can be built against the Python installation.  It is all about support for third-party tools.

In general, day-to-day user has no need for those files.  It mainly affects them when they are installing an external tool that needs to be recompiled.

Comment: Nice to see your answers... big fan here! (sorry about the spam, couldn't help myself)